# How to append to formula if a condition is met in microsoft excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros, automation

I have a bunch of formulas dotted about my excel tab that are of the form:

`=cell_1+0.0049>SUM(cell_2:cell_3)` for example-

`=O10+0.0049>SUM(H10:N10)`

I want to find all instances of these cells and append the following:

```
-OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-6)
```

so my example becomes-

```
=O10+0.0049>SUM(H10:N10)-OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-6)
```

Is there an easy way to do this in excel or vba?

The `0.049>SUM` is unique to the cells I want to append to.

What I have managed to do so far is identify the cells I want to append to using the following:

`0.049>SUM*` the `*` wildcard helps me run through all the cells that need appending but I'm not sure how to do this over the whole sheet and how to append?

EDIT: I have managed to get the VBA to select the relevant cells but I'm not sure how to get it to append the bit I want and also to do it over the entire sheet.

```
Cells.Find(What:="0.0049>SUM", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Comment: Excel capabilities for find & replace are very limited. It would be simpler to use Google Sheets where regex is fully built-into the find & replace dialog.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `.Find` to find the first occurrence and then `.FindNext` to keep finding any others.

[Range.Find](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find)

[Range.FindNext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext)

I have used `ws.Cells`, but you could easily change it to `Selection` so that it only searches within the selected cells.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AppendToFormula()

Dim find_in_formula As String
Dim append_to_formula As String
Dim found_cell As Range
Dim first_address As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

'the value you want to find in the formulas on the active sheet
find_in_formula = "0.049>SUM"

'the value you want to append to each found formula
append_to_formula = "-OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-6)"

'the currently active sheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws.Cells
    
    'find the first occurrence of the formula
    Set found_cell = .Find(find_in_formula, , xlFormulas)
    
    'if we have found the formula
    If Not found_cell Is Nothing Then
    
        'store the location of the first occurrence of the formula
        first_address = found_cell.Address
        
        
        Do
            'append the text to the end of the formula
            found_cell.Formula2 = found_cell.Formula2 & append_to_formula
            
            'look for the next occurrence of the formula
            Set found_cell = .FindNext(found_cell)
            
            'when find_next reaches the end of the search, it wraps around
            'to the beginning. If we have returned to the original cell
            'then stop - we're done
            If found_cell.Address = first_address Then Exit Do
            
            'keep searching until nothing is found
        Loop While Not found_cell Is Nothing
    End If
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't do anything? It gets to the ```If Not found_cell Is Nothing Then``` and then doesn't enter the loop?!?!

Comment: Oh, it's because in your post your formula has 0.0049, but you then said "0.049" is common. So, edit the line find_in_formula to include another zero.

Comment: My bad hahaaa it is late and I'm tired! I will mark this as accepted but would like to give people a bit more time to respond if that's okay.

Comment: @FlexYourData Don't you think that the construction proposed by the author of the question `-OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-6)` is somewhat cumbersome? Perhaps a line like `found_cell.FormulaR1C1 = found_cell.FormulaR1C1 & "-RC[-6]"` would be better?

Comment: To be totally honest, I didn't even consider reviewing and editing the details of the replacement text, but you might be correct. How does such a formula appear in the spreadsheet if OP is not using R1C1 address styles?